# How can I download website using .NET

Tags: .net

Does anybody know how can I download a website using .NET?
Is there any open source tool for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "website" ? One site like Googles Homepage or a complete site ?

Comment: A complete website or just one HTML-Document?

Comment: Can you be more specific about this? Do you need the html or complete site with pictures, scipts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), It's the de-facto library to connect, download, parse and process HTML from remote sites, local files, etc.